# Utilização de SyntaxTree

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Estou estudando C# e me deparei com o `SyntaxTree` enquanto lia sobre `Roslyn`.

Fiz também a leitura da documentação da própria Microsoft no link: 
[Introdução à análise de sintaxe](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis)

No entanto ainda tenho duas dúvidas, apenas para fixação do conteúdo que estou estudando.

As dúvidas são:

- Em que a SyntaxTree pode ser realmente útil na minha aplicação?
- Quando devo utilizar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Para a maioria das aplicações para nada. É útil se você for fazer algum analisador estático de código ou alguma ferramenta semelhante.

Answer (score 1):

Gean, boa tarde!
Como dito no início do post que você utilizou como base para a pergunta, poderia dizer que a utilidade em sistemas comuns, comerciais, seria zero mesmo como já disse o grande Maniero. A funcionalidade da classe em questão vem única e exclusivamente para listar pontos da estrutura de um sistema conforme a citação a seguir (retirada do texto inicial):

> Essas estruturas de dados têm detalhes suficientes para que possam
>   representar qualquer programa, de qualquer tamanho. Essas estruturas
>   podem descrever programas completos que compilam e executam
>   corretamente. Elas também podem descrever programas incompletos,
>   enquanto você os escreve no editor.